# MySql query result replacing unordered list values in html file

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

----- The problem is solved -> solution down below -----

I have html file where there is a dropdown menu for different courses (as listed below):

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropbtn" id="1">
        <a href="">first</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content"> // we should get the content from the query (the names)
            <li><a href="#">value1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">value2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropbtn" id="2">
        <a href="">second</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">value3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">value4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
         .
         .
         .
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The first year is with id=1, second with id=2 and so on. I also have mySQL database with courses (id, name, year, resources) and want to make a query where I get the name if the year value is equal to the given id from the html file. For example:

```
SELECT name
FROM subject
WHERE id=1;
```

I want my dropdown content (class="dropdown-content" > li) to have the result of this query. For example if the result for id=1 is UP and OOP, I want value1 and value2 replaces with UP and OOP. I read a lot of topics and couldn't find anything like that. I would be thankful if someone can give me tips or ideas on how to solve my problem. Should I use ajax, php or what? Have a great week!

---------------------FIXED---------------------------

I made a php file where I have functions for executing the query and making the list of different subjects which looks like this:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", '', "fmi_courses");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    $mysqli->character_set_name();
}

function ExecuteQuery($mysqli, $id_num) 
{
    $res = $mysqli->query("Select name, course, id FROM subject WHERE course='$id_num'");
    return $res;
}

function GetCourseName($mysqli, $id_num)
{
    $result = ExecuteQuery($mysqli, $id_num);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<li id='.$row["id"].'><a href="#">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Then I simply include it in the html file with
    
And insert call the GetCourseName function in the dropdown-content class.

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropbtn" id="1">
        <a href="">first</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content"> 
            <?php GetCourseName($mysqli, 1) ?> // here I call the function
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropbtn" id="2">
        <a href="">second</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <?php GetCourseName($mysqli, 2) ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
         .
         .
         .
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Google order by

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use PHP.
First you need to do is select all your data from table if needed.

Then save them as json or array if you want.

use for each to loop the data from your array or json

```
<?php foreach($dataArray as $key = > $val){  ?>
   <ul>
    <li class="dropbtn" id="<?php  $val->id ?>">
       <a href="">first</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#"><?php $val->name ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">value2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You helped me with the idea of how to fix it and I'll write it below so it can possibly help others with the same problem as me.

Comment: @user3136734 please kindly up this answer. Thanks